# How to display weekly historical data (yahoo finance) from friday to friday?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

```
df=yf.download("^NSEI", start="2020-11-30", end="2022-02-27",interval="1wk")
```

I'm trying to download the historical data from yahoo finance using Yfinance  & Pandas it works fine.
But it takes the weekly range as Monday to Monday
I want it from Friday to Friday basis .

Is it possible ? Any help would be appreciated ! thanks!!

Comment: Is it crucial to use `yfinance`?

Comment: Not really. Any other means will do.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't change `yfinance` settings in order to have weekly data, which has a Friday-to-Friday range.
However, you can download daily data and manually resample it to fit your needs.

You can use Pandas' `resample` function if you are interested in only, let's say, the adjusted closing prices.

```
df=yf.download("^NSEI", start="2020-11-30", end="2022-02-27")
df_daily_close = df.loc[:, "Adj Close"]
df_weekly_close = df_daily_close.resample("W-FRI").last()
```

If you want to resample OHLCV prices, you can use the `aggregate` function along with the `resample` function. The aggregate function allows you to apply different functions to different columns in the dataframe.

```
# Remove the `Close` column as we are using `Adj Close`
df_daily_ohlcv = df.drop("Close", axis=1)

# Define a dictionary with the functions to apply to each column
functions = {"Open": "first", "High": "max", "Low": "min", "Adj Close": "last", "Volume": "sum"}

# Resample
df_weekly_ohlcv = df.resample('W-FRI').aggregate(functions)
```